# What's a good FOSS X-platform self-hosted VOIP program?

Tags: open-source, self-hosted, voip

I'm looking for a VOIP program that fits these following criterion.

- I can host the server myself via port forwarding.
- FOSS. Free as in freedom and preferably as in beer.
- X-platform. It needs to work for Linux (Debian derivatives) and Windows.
- User friendly via GUI elements. I'm a hacker, but my friends are not.
- Allows for multiple people in one call.

Is there any such software?

Comment: In the bounty notes, when I say "relatively comprehensive list", I mean perhaps ~a dozen of the most popular voip programs / services.

Comment: My first read of the title caused me to wonder "what's the FOSS X platform?".  After rereading it a couple times, I saw the critical dash. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have several options here, depending on if you're "just" looking for VOIP or if you're also looking for Video Chat. I've listed a couple, but there are likely to be MANY more options.

For video chat, I've used [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org), which, when checked today (2021-03-02) has a self hosting guide on their Github repository. https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-quickstart

- [X] Self-hosted with port forwarding
- [X] FOSS (Apache licensed)
- [X] Cross-platform (uses a web browser and WebRTC)
- [X] GUI elements (uses a web browser and WebRTC)
- [X] Multiple people in one call

[Matrix.org](https://matrix.org) uses Jitsi as their embedded Video-Call software. In fact, the [commonly suggested Ansible Playbook for deploying Matrix's reference home server](https://github.com/spantaleev/matrix-docker-ansible-deploy) also includes Jitsi as an optional install component. Matrix also has text chat, is decentralized and self-hostable. It was recently used to facilitate the online FOSDEM event, and is the chat platform for the Mozilla and KDE communities.

If you only want VOIP, I've used [Mumble](https://mumble.info) and it's server component Murmur before. While I've not installed Murmur recently, I know it can be installed as part of the Windows client, so let's check your list of requirements:

- [X] Self-hosted with port forwarding
- [X] FOSS (Appears to be BSD licensed? Either way the boilerplate is very small.)
- [X] Cross-platform (Windows, Mac, Linux from the project, 3rd party Android and iOS clients)
- [X] GUI elements (totally GUI - no web interface)
- [X] Multiple people in one call

Comment: Mumble looks like it fits the bill. I'll test it out this evening. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in NextCloud and it's Talk component.

NextCloud is a collaboration software suite, so it's not exactly a dedicated VOIP service, but with it has web and mobile app support for it's Talk component which can handle voice and video calling.